# XOR: Is it possible to get $a$ and $b$ if I have $a \oplus b$ and $a \times b$?

Tags: mathematics

Intuitively I would say yes but I can't find a way to prove it. I tried with small values and bruteforcing shows that there seems to only be one solution given a distinct tuplet.

For example $(1,72)$ has only $(8,9)$ as valid $a$ and $b$ values. Is there a way to do this mathematically?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! For the uninitiated in the room (such as me), would you mind explaining what precisely is meant by the little symbol that looks like a Phillips head screw? Thanks, and have a great day!

Comment: It’s [bitwise addition modulo 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839479/what-does-a-circled-plus-mean), @Brandon_J

Comment: Thanks for letting me know,  @El-Guest .

Comment: So essentially, I convert the number to binary (for exapmle, 3-->00011, 24-->11000), then perform theXOR  operation on each pair of bits, and then convert back to a normal number (27)?

Comment: Not sure this is a *puzzle*, but I'm glad you got your answer. (Please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By counterexample, $a,b$ pair is clearly not unique.

> The pairs $(5,9)$ and $(3,15)$ both multiply to $45$, and add bitwise to $12$.
>
>  $5 \oplus 9 = 12$,  $5 \times 9 = 45$
>  $3 \oplus 15 = 12$,  $3 \times 15 = 45$

Comment: @Hugh, thanks for the edits - looks nicer now!

Comment: I edited it quickly off my phone a few hours ago, so I have it another go. Hopefully it still looks good.